# JQuery Webui Popover shows even Trigger Manual is specified

Tags: jquery, uipopover

I'm using Webui Popover plugin for popovers on a page.

[Webui Popver](https://github.com/sandywalker/webui-popover)

Then I initialised popover as

```
$('div.score-range').webuiPopover({
    type: 'html',
    placement: 'left',
    width: 400,
    delay: {//show and hide delay time of the popover, works only when trigger is 'hover',the value can be number or object
        show: null,
        hide: 30000
    },
    closeable: true,
    trigger: 'manual',
    title:
        return "Score Range"; ,
    content: function () {

        return "My Content"
    }
})
```

But the problem is even I specified manual option in the trigger , its being shows on hovering the button to which the popover is assigned.

But I would like to trigger this on clicking the button. Im not using the **click** trigger since I've something more to do the button click event and if some condition is satisfied then the popover has to show.

So only on the click event of the button the popover should show. So I can show the popover using

```
$('#mybutton').webuiPopover('show');
```

But the popver is showing when hovering that button even trigger manual is specified.

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Did you try with "click"? You can assign any number of events on the same element so that should work just fine.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Yes.. I tried with click. But the reason I tried manual is, I dont want to open the popover either by click or hover directly according to the situation. I just need to show it only in a condition of the button click also because I need to assign some data to the popover buttons in the button click which is actually calculated value.

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in the library. One problem with jQuery is that it evolves pretty fast so webuiPopover may not be 100% compatible with the latest versions. Have you checked the list of bugs reported on github.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Thanks for that info. It was actually a bug with the library as you mentioned. But I replaced Webui popover with Bootstrap popover which runs fine with the requirement..